# Changing body image with an onClick Event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was wondering how would I approach to change a body background image with onClick Event. Should I be using useRef hook or. I would really appriciate the help

```
body {
  background: url("http");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
}


function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={...}> click here to change background image </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `document.body.style.backgroundImage` like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const IMAGES = [
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/08/25/22/22/saturn-54999_1280.jpg",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/06/01/33/sky-5375005_1280.jpg",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2011/12/14/12/23/solar-system-11111_1280.jpg"
  ];

  const changeBodyBgImage = () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${IMAGES[counter]})`;
    setCounter(counter > 2 ? 0 : counter + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={changeBodyBgImage}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-brook-82prg?file=/src/App.js:0-665

Comment: Why I can not add transition when image changes

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.body` to set the background changes you need.
The event handler should look like this.

```
onClick={() => {
    document.body.style.background = ...
}}
```